# How do I receive UDP packets from a remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I'm trying to read some values from a device with a few analog inputs and PWM outputs to control a LED strip. The device responds to UDP packets it receives via Ethernet. I have some documentation on the packet format and can send any color I like.

But my Python 3 program (running on Win 10 or a Raspberry Pi) can't receive the reply from the device when I'm requesting the value of an analog input. When I use Wireshark, I see the device sends back UDP reply packets in the expected format. But the data from these packets is not received in my application and the timeout on the socket just expires.

So basically, I would like to understand how to receive UDP packets from a remote 'server'. (I hope it's correct to consider that remote device to be the server in this case?)

I'm new to Python programming, so advice on code styling etc... is also appreciated.

Please have a look at my code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from threading import Thread
import socket
import select
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont

DEVICE_IP = "10.10.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 11991

myOutputPkt  = bytearray([0x88, 0x77, 0x66, 0x55, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x04, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
myRequestPkt = bytearray([0x88, 0x77, 0x66, 0x44, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x04, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

win = tkinter.Tk()

myFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 16, weight = 'bold')

def sendOutput(IOnumber, IOvalue):
        myOutputPkt[10] = IOnumber
        myOutputPkt[11] = IOvalue & 0xff
        myOutputPkt[12] = (IOvalue & 0xff00) >> 8
        myOutputPkt[13] = (IOvalue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        myOutputPkt[14] = (IOvalue & 0xff000000) >> 24
        sock.sendto(myOutputPkt, (DEVICE_IP, UDP_PORT))

def sendColors():
        redValue = sliderR.get()
        greenValue = sliderG.get()
        blueValue = sliderB.get()
        print('Sending RGB colors(', redValue, greenValue, blueValue,')')
        sendOutput(2, redValue)
        sendOutput(3, greenValue)
        sendOutput(4, blueValue)

def getValue(IOnumber):
        myRequestPkt[11] = IOnumber & 0xff
        myRequestPkt[12] = (IOnumber & 0xff00) >> 8
        myRequestPkt[13] = (IOnumber & 0xff0000) >> 16
        myRequestPkt[14] = (IOnumber & 0xff000000) >> 24

        try:
            print('Sending request...')
            sent = sock.sendto(myRequestPkt, (DEVICE_IP, UDP_PORT))
            sock.setblocking(0)

            ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 5) # timeout_in_seconds
            if ready[0]:
                data = sock.recv(100)
                print(data)

        finally:
            print('closing socket')
            sock.close()

def exitProgram():
        print("Exit Button pressed")
        win.quit()

win.title("playing with UDP packets to control RGB LEDs")
win.geometry('800x600')

colorButton = Button(win, text = "send colors", font = myFont, command = sendColors, height = 1, width = 16)
colorButton.pack()

sliderR = tkinter.Scale(win, from_ = 0, to = 1000, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
sliderR.set(200)
sliderR.pack()
sliderG = tkinter.Scale(win, from_ = 0, to = 1000, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
sliderG.set(250)
sliderG.pack()
sliderB = tkinter.Scale(win, from_ = 0, to = 1000, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
sliderB.set(300)
sliderB.pack()

anaButton = Button(win, text = "get analog value", font = myFont, command = getValue, height = 1, width = 16)
anaButton.pack()

exitButton = Button(win, text = "exit", font = myFont, command = exitProgram, height = 1, width = 16)
exitButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

mainloop()
```

Comment: if you're after general advice I'd suggest checking out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if you're after help with networking/sockets then I'd suggest removing all the other unrelated (Tk) code.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info